# Is there any correlation between temperature and illness?

Tags: biology, disease

How many times did you hear your mother tell you, "Put on a jacket or you're going to catch a cold!" or "Come in out of the rain before you catch cold!"

It's also a fairly common trope in Jane Austen-esque type movies that someone will be out in the rain and succumb to a high fever as a direct result to the chill.

Is there any truth to being cold directly correlating to fever or general illness?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does being cold increase your chances of catching the common cold?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/88/does-being-cold-increase-your-chances-of-catching-the-common-cold)

Comment: Answers the question about colds, but what about fevers/chills?

Comment: fevers and chills are not sicknesses. A "cold's" symptom is usually a fever. your claimed phrases even include your going to catch a "cold".

Comment: also, if your cold to long you'll get hypothermia, http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hypothermia/basics/definition/con-20020453

Comment: In a more general sense, living in a cold climate reduces or eliminates the chance of catching many pretty nasty illnesess - Wikipedia has a list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_disease  I also think (personal opinion) that spending time outdoors in cold weather reduces the chance of catching airborne communicable diseases.  And maybe it's semantics, but I don't think htypothermia should be considered a illness, it's more like an injury.

Comment: @jamesqf Illness = an unhealthy condition of body or mind.
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illness
if the OP wants to specifically state a virus/bacterial infection then he needs to fix his post otherwise, hypothermia fits the bill nicely. And you would call it a Disorder, most likely. The "chills" would also be another name for hypothermia, shaking cold, ect. fever is in referance to a bacterial or virual infection, and as rjzii pointed out, cold temp helps viral infections. "cold temperatures and low relative humidity are favorable to the spread of influenza virus."

Comment: Also if the op clarifies for viral, then this is a dupe.

Comment: @Himarm: So would e.g. breaking your leg while skiing count as a cold-related illness?  Also note from the same link that illness is "a specific condition that prevents your body or mind from working normally : a sickness or disease".

Comment: @Himarm: Also note that cases of hypothermia are probably balanced out by cases of hyperthermia, AKA heat stroke.

Comment: @Sklivvz I'm not avoiding a play on worlds, he asked does being cold result in "general Illness". Hypothermia is a direct result of being cold, it disables your body, and can potentially kill you.

Comment: I closed this as unclear because the notable claims are about common colds (duplicate) and the first answer was about hypothermia (which doesn't seem to be an answer, but is apparently disputable, showing the question is unclear.)